# Moving Average with Current Value Included in tableau

Tags: tableau-api, moving-average

I was going through tableau tutorial and there I came across this Moving Average. I know that If I want to Calculate moving average I can do that from "Quick Calculation Table ( Where the default Moving average is for previous 2 days)".

[Data Source](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xhFsJ3Goam3w0hK-Mh6X1xF8erdN5fdz)

Sample Data Screenshot
[image]

Below shown Image is the Quick Calculation of Moving Average for previous 3 Days.

[image]

Here is the sample data from the above shown figure:

[image]

So, If I want to Calculate previous 3 days moving average for **3rd Jan 2014** ( Including the current date), the calculation will be like:

(2955+4391+2481)/3= 3255 ,Which is the result I am also Getting in Tableau Screenshot Show below :

[image]

Now I am finding the moving average for 4th Jan 2014 ( Including the Current Date), the calculation will follow like :

(4391+2418+2815)/3= 3,208, But I am not getting the same Result in the Tableau as shown in the Screenshot below :
[image]

**Here as you can see that the Moving average is 3,145 and my calculated moving average is 3,208.**

**Why tableau results are not same as mine manually calculated result ?**

Below the The Screenshot of my "Edit Calculation box " Tableau:
[image]

Comment: What level of granularity is your data, sales per store per day, or just sales per day?

Comment: @hello_friend Well the Actual Data is Sales per store per day. But I think at the end the plotted data will be total of sales of every store for that specific day.

Comment: I suspect the previous 3 values your equation is fetching relate to each individual store and not the aggregated sales figure. Consider first aggregating your sales variable to the day level and then applying a secondary running average equation on top of this and then check the result.

Comment: @hello_friend I have edited my post with link to data source and sample data screenshot. As you can see in the Screenshot that sales data for 1st Jan 2014 with shope ID :NYFLO152 is 70.290 and the data for the first jan in the given table is 2955

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because your Tableau moving average is looking at the past 3 values plus the current. Which is 4 values. You want to look at the past 2 values plus the current value.

Simple to fix - edit your table calc to look at the past 2 Previous Values, not the 3 how it's currently set.

Comment: What if the previous value is not available ? What will happen in that case?

Comment: It will go back the spaces you specify - if there's nothing there it will do nothing. So doing the moving avg calc on the first date should return the same value as the same date.